# Lost my Password! Please help!

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, password

I was working on this new puzzle for quite some time now. Unfortunately, I locked the file and now I don't remember the password... `:(`

Here's a snapshot. I think I might have left some clues for cracking it. But I am lost..Not sure what was it..

[image]

**Transcript of file name**

> ```
>  WFBEBOCLECHKLBPM
> ```

**Can you help me find my password?**

**Hint**

> As already observed in comments, start by recognizing the file type. And then utilize [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography).

Comment: That looks like a really cluttered desktop in the background... maybe cleaning that up would help ;)

Comment: Can you maybe write the file name out?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Isn't it easily visible? Anyway, lets add it :-) Didn't add it initially coz I felt its more of a visual as well :-)

Comment: Some people want to be able to easily copy/paste things that may be useful ^

Comment: Some people just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: @Rubio it's just, you see, there are these three things out of quite a lot. These things are called 'keys'. They are found on keyboards, commonly associated with laptops and computers. These particular keys are called 'ctrl', 'c' and 'v'. They all do different things but together can form magic. You see, 'ctrl' and 'c' are amazing friends who note down everything they see. 'ctrl' and 'v', are also friends but they love writing things really, really fast. Together, they can duplicate text. It makes things very easy.  Don't worry if you don't understand, it is *very* complicated. :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil **[Where's the ctrl key? There doesn't seem to be any ctrl key! All I see is ⌘, ⌥, ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st6-DgWeuos)**

Comment: crack it with "enigma password cracker"

Comment: @Techidiot the wheel numbers should be unique, I hope you have taken that into account

Comment: @Netham Didn't get you. :-/

Comment: @Jamal Senjaya - Wish it was that easy ':-(

Comment: @Techidiot I am interpreting 411 has significance. If this is an enigma cipher then 411 point out to wheel numbers, but they have to be unique in the sense they cannot be 411, they can be 412 or 421 (two wheels cannot have the same value)

Comment: I assume that the :( in your question mean something, because it has been highlighted. Also, the file format is .ISO, a virtual disk format, so i assume the C directory means something..

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia I think, there is no [tag:story] tag here.

Comment: @Netham Where does 411 appear in the question?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It used to be a larger picture that showed the 411 KB file size and creation date but the image was reduced to help us focus on what is supposedly important to the solution

Comment: On the face of it, there doesn't seem much more to this than "Here's some ciphertext: WFBEBOCLECHKLBPM. Now decipher it!" which is plainly unreasonable. So perhaps there's some other clue hidden somewhere.

Comment: @Netham Oh! I'd forgotten that the image was different before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your password is

> Welldone

The icon is a

> Windows Standard icon for .ISO files

Which leads us to interpret the filename as

> ISO 2-digit Country Codes

[As deduced in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36673225#36673225)
From there, I looked at the list

> And took the n'th letter of each entry,
> **W**allis & Futuna, B**e**lgium, Bo**l**ivia, Chi**l**e, Ecua**d**or, Hong K**o**ng, Lebano**n**, and Saint-Pi**e**rre & Miquelon

Comment: Yay! We did it!